# running an executable file in cgi

Tags: unix, cgi, executable

when i use unix shell commands in a cgi script they run fine. if i add an executable file, it will not run. (Only the unix commands will be executed and not the executable program that just outputs some numbers) How can i make the executable's output appear ?
The file contents are: (WHERE '"a.cgi" is a binary executable)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html\n"
echo "<html><head></head><body> <h2> Hi Boy</h2>"
echo "<pre>"
ls -l
a.cgi
cat tt.f
echo "</pre>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Comment: You need to provide more information: 1. what are the file permissions of that executable? 2. where is it located, is it _really_ inside the `PATH`? 3. why does that executable have such a strange file name extension? (Not that the extension matters, but it looks very odd...)...

Comment: The webserver session might run with a special user like `nobody`, having a minimal set of rights. First try testing with standard commands like `echo "This works"`, `pwd`, `who`, `ps -f` and `echo "path=${PATH}"`.